# How do I fix a npm WARN lifecycle error from Namecheap?

Tags: node.js, npm, hosting, npm-install, namecheap

This is the error I'm getting when I run NPM install in Namecheap Cpanel:

```
Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
```

I tried adding a file at the root folder of the app, called .npmrc, place this line into it:

`scripts-prepend-node-path=true`

but that didn't work.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install my modules manually through Namecheaps terminal/ssh.